# What does "latter" refer to? and How the last part of the sentence?

Tags: meaning

https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20171108-the-uncertain-future-of-handwriting

> She explains that two of the most common arguments she hears from
> detractors regarding the decline of handwriting is that not protecting
> it will result in a “loss of history” and a “loss of personal touch”.
>
> On the former she counters that 95% of handwritten manuscripts can’t
> be read by the average person anyway – “that’s why we have
> paleographers,” she explains, paleography being the study of ancient
> styles of writing – *while the **latter** refers to the warm
> associations we give to handwritten personal notes, such as thank-you
> cards.*

I just find it difficult to understand the last part of the sentence here, and how the "latter" works.
Thank you for help!

Comment: The antecedents here are this, which you did not post: She explains that two of the most common arguments she hears from detractors regarding the decline of handwriting is that not protecting it will result in a “**loss of history**” [former] and a “**loss of personal touch**”.[latter]

Answer (score 2):

*Former* and *latter* refer to the first and the last of two previously mentioned things. I have put them in bold in the more complete quotation below and identified them {so}.

“She explains that two of the most common arguments she hears from detractors regarding the decline of handwriting is that not protecting it will result in a “**loss of history**” and a “**loss of personal touch**”.

On the former {the loss of history} she counters that 95% of handwritten manuscripts can’t be read by the average person anyway – “that’s why we have paleographers,” she explains, paleography being the study of ancient styles of writing – while the latter {loss of personal touch} refers to the warm associations we give to handwritten personal notes, such as thank-you cards.”